# Нужно ли здесь тире

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли здесь тире?
**У нас на сайте верхняя одежда - более 1000 наименований.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше использовать такой вариант: На нашем сайте представлен **широкий ассортимент** верхней одежды – более 1000 наименований.

Обособление уточняющей присоединительной конструкции.

Answer (score 2):

Возможен такой вариант: **На нашем сайте представлено более 1000 наименований  верхней одежды.**